# Calling `useVal` several times in a single function with arrays - unexpected behavior

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm calling my `useArr` function several times within a single function call. With each call to `useArr`, I'm pushing a new value to the existing `arr` function. I'm staggering each call with a `pause` function.

Instead of rendering the string of `abcde` in a stepwise, interval fashion, it simply overrides the previous letter. My understanding of hooks under the hood isn't great, so I'd appreciate if anyone could offer insight.

To give some context as to why I'm writing this unconventional code, I'm trying to simulate how a websocket would interact with the app, if anyone was wondering :)

```js
const App = () => {
  const [arr, useArr] = useState([])
  return (
    <div>
      {arr}
      <button onClick={increment}>Click meh</button>
    </div>
  )
  async function increment() {
    useArr([...arr, 'a'])
    await pause()
    useArr([...arr, 'b'])
    await pause()
    useArr([...arr, 'c'])
    await pause()
    useArr([...arr, 'd'])
    await pause()
    useArr([...arr, 'e'])
    await pause()
  }
  async function pause() {
    return new Promise(_=>setTimeout(_, 500))
  }
}

export { App }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: You should be using the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) syntax.

This is really more about understanding JavaScript closures than it is about hooks. To demonstrate what is going on, here is some code based on your `increment` method, but without any hooks -- just plain JavaScript.

```
  async function increment() {
    const arr = [];
    let nextArr = undefined;
    nextArr = [...arr, 'a'];
    await pause()
    nextArr = [...arr, 'b'];
    await pause()
    nextArr = [...arr, 'c'];
    await pause()
    nextArr = [...arr, 'd'];
    await pause()
    nextArr = [...arr, 'e'];
    await pause()
  }
```

At the end of this function, what do you expect the value of `nextArr` to be? `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` or `['e']` (hint: you've already seen the result in your app)

`nextArr` represents what you are passing in to your state setter.

As a side note, I recommend you use the naming convention of `setArr` rather than `useArr` for the setter variable name. `useX` should be reserved for custom hooks -- not used for state setters.

What you meant to be doing is something like the following:

```
  async function increment() {
    const arr = [];
    let nextArr = undefined;
    nextArr = [...arr, 'a'];
    await pause()
    nextArr = [...nextArr, 'b'];
    await pause()
    nextArr = [...nextArr, 'c'];
    await pause()
    nextArr = [...nextArr, 'd'];
    await pause()
    nextArr = [...nextArr, 'e'];
    await pause()
  }
```

This code leverages the previous value to create the next value. The [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) syntax can be used to get this effect. With the functional update syntax and the naming change I suggested, your `increment` function would look like this:

```
  async function increment() {
    setArr(prevArr => [...prevArr, 'a'])
    await pause()
    setArr(prevArr => [...prevArr, 'b'])
    await pause()
    setArr(prevArr => [...prevArr, 'c'])
    await pause()
    setArr(prevArr => [...prevArr, 'd'])
    await pause()
    setArr(prevArr => [...prevArr, 'e'])
    await pause()
  }
```

[image: Edit array functional state update]