# Not able to manage multiple jssip phone session request in react

Tags: reactjs, render, jssip

Working one react project based on functional components only.

Project contains Audio Call functions using JSSIP. Calling functions working fine with single call.

When multiple call happens I can able to display multiple calling popup at bottom of app like below screenshot

[image]

Component loads multiple times when NewRTCSession called so I used **useRef** for storing all sesison.

Till now everything working fine.

Now when I press **End Call** from browser **endCall()** methods and **terminate()** session.

Now when call ends at that time session of JSSIP calls **failed** event calls.

Adding code now.

```
const messageHandler = (message, participants, setParticipants) => {
    setParticipants({
        ...participants,
        [message.request.call_id]: message
    });
    const session = message.session;
    session.on('failed', (e) => {
        try {
            delete participants[message.request.call_id];
            setParticipants(participants);
        } catch(ex) {
        }
    });
};

function IncomingCall() {
    const [participants, setParticipants] = React.useState({});
    const participantsRef = React.useRef(participants);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        participantsRef.current = participants;
    });
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handler = (message) => {messageHandler(message, participantsRef.current, setParticipants)};
        const phone = JsSipHelper.ua();
        phone.on("newRTCSession", handler);
    }, []);

    const endCall = (id) => {
        participants[id].session.terminate();
    };

    return (
        <div id="meetingRoom">
            {Object.keys(participants).map((participant, index) => (
                <div>
                    <h1>Call From: {participants[participant].session.remote_identity.display_name}</h1>
                    <button onClick={() => endCall()}>End Call</button>
                    <button>Answer Call</button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default IncomingCall;
```

When **endCall()** calls from first call section, Call in mobile gets end successfully. Now **failed** event calls and I am trying to update state variable of **participants** but it that variable clear completely.

But now I am waiting for call ends in mobile after timeout so it's happens and again that popup comes in ui.

So, I am confused here. How **state** and **useRef** going to work with multiple.

**Reference**

[UseEffect hook with socket.io state is not persistent in socket handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824036/useeffect-hook-with-socket-io-state-is-not-persistent-in-socket-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at https://github.com/OpenTelecom/react-sip-phone

It's a react webphone using SIP.js which supports several sessions.