# useEffect re-renders twice with socket.io

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm still new to react, but I'm currently facing a issue regarding to updating the state; I'm making use of socket.io and  change streams to check for any updates in the database (post document). Every time a new post is created, the useEffect seems to be logging twice, one is the change that has been made in the socket.io and the iterating array which I mainly want. So some how it's causing the useEffect to render twice. How would I go about on fixing this? Any help would be really appreciated!

## Issue (console.log)

[console.log() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iwv3.png)

## Server/Change Stream/Socket Emit()

```
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', () => {
    console.log(chalk.blueBright("Setting change streams"));
    db.collection('posts').watch()
    .on('change', change => {
        if(change.operationType === 'insert'){
            console.log(chalk.yellowBright('INSERTED'))
            io.emit('posts', change.fullDocument);
        }
    });
    db.collection('posts').watch({ fullDocument: 'updateLookup' })
    .on('change', change => {
        if(change.operationType === 'update'){
            console.log(chalk.yellowBright('UPDATED'));
            io.emit('posts', change.fullDocument);
        }
    })

});
```

## Client side

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/post/posts",config).then((response) => {
        setPosts(response.data);
    });
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('posts', (item) => {
       console.log([...posts, item]);
    })
},[posts])

const postHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(newPost(uname, upic, messages, media));
    setMessages('');
}
```

I have done a bit of reading regarding re-rendering would normally occur due to React.StrictMode being in use, but I guess that wouldn't be the case as I have removed it. Below I'll provide the full client code, don't mind the length.

## Full Client Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import '../../styles/private/dashboard.css';
import DashboardHeader from '../../components/private/templates/header';
import DashboardSidebar from '../../components/private/templates/sidebar';
import ImageSearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ImageSearch';
import VideoLibraryIcon from '@material-ui/icons/VideoLibrary';
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';
import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { newPost } from '../../redux/actions/posts/new-post';
import { likePost } from '../../redux/actions/posts/like-post';
import { getPosts } from '../../redux/actions/posts/get-posts';
import { unlikePost } from '../../redux/actions/posts/unlike-post';
import { getPostLikes } from '../../redux/actions/posts/get-likes';
import { likePostComment } from '../../redux/actions/posts/like-comment';
import { unlikePostComment } from '../../redux/actions/posts/unlike-comment';
import { newPostComment } from '../../redux/actions/posts/new-post-comment';
import ChatBubbleOutlineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChatBubbleOutline';
import LoopIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Loop';
import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder';
import MoreHorizIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
import FlipMove from 'react-flip-move';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

function Dashboard({ history, getPost, getLike, getAllPosts, getAllLikes, likePosts, unlikePosts}) {
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState('');
    const [media, setMedia] = useState(null);
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [comment, setComment] = useState();
    const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
    const { user } = userLogin;
    const [uname, setUname] =useState(user.name);
    const [upic, setUpic] = useState(user.pic);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`, 
        },
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!cookies.get('authToken')){
            history.push('/login');
        }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    },[history]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("/api/post/posts",config).then((response) => {
            setPosts(response.data);
        });
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('posts', (item) => {
            console.log([...posts, item]);
        })
    },[posts])

    const postHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(newPost(uname, upic, messages, media));
        setMessages('');
    }

    const LikePost = (postId) => {
        likePosts(postId, user._id, user.name, user.pic);
    }

    const UnlikePost = (postId) => {
        unlikePosts(postId);
    }

    const submitComment = (postId) => {
        dispatch(newPostComment(postId, uname, upic, comment));
        setComment('');
    }

    const LikeCommentPost = (postId, commentId) => {
        dispatch(likePostComment(postId, commentId, user._id, user.name, user.pic));
    }

    const UnlikeCommentPost = (postId, commentId) => {
        dispatch(unlikePostComment(postId, commentId));
    }

    return error ? (
        <span>{error}</span>
    ):(
        <div className="dashboard">
            <DashboardHeader/>
            <div className="dashboard__container">
                <div className="dashboard__sidebar">
                    <DashboardSidebar/>
                </div>
                <div className="dashboard__content">
                    <div className="dashboard__contentLeft">
                        <div className="dashboard__messenger">
                            <div className="dashboard__messengerTop">
                                <Avatar src={user.pic} className="dashboard__messengerAvatar"/>
                                <input type="text" placeholder={`What's on your mind, ${user.name}`} value={messages} onChange={(e) => setMessages(e.target.value)}/>
                                <SendIcon className="dashboard__messengerPostButton" onClick={postHandler}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="dashboard__messengerBottom">
                                <ImageSearchIcon className="dashboard__messengerImageIcon" value={media} onChange={(e) => setMedia((e) => e.target.value)}/>
                                <VideoLibraryIcon className="dashboard__messengerVideoIcon"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="dashboard__postsContainer">
                            <FlipMove>
                                {posts.map((post,i) => (
                                    <div className="dashboard__post" key={i}>
                                        <MoreHorizIcon className="dashboard__postOptions"/>
                                        <div className="dashboard__postTop">
                                            <Avatar className="dashboard__postUserPic" src={post.upic}/>
                                            <h3>{post.uname}</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="dashboard__postBottom">
                                            <p>{post.message}</p>
                                        {media === null ? '':(
                                            <div className="dashboard__postMedia">
                                                {media}
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="dashboard__postActions">
                                            {toggle ? (
                                                <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)} className="dashboard__actionComment"/>
                                            ): (
                                                <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)} className="dashboard__actionComment"/>
                                            )}
                                            <label id='totalLikes' className="dashboard__comments" style={{color: 'forestgreen'}}>
                                                    {post.commentCount}
                                            </label>

                                            {post.likes.find(like => like.uid === user._id) ? (
                                                <FavoriteIcon onClick={() => UnlikePost(post._id)} className="dashboard__actionUnlike"/>
                                            ):(
                                                <FavoriteBorderIcon onClick={() => LikePost(post._id)} className="dashboard__actionLike"/>
                                            )}              
                                                <label id='totalLikes' className="dashboard__likes" style={{color: 'forestgreen'}}>
                                                    {post.likeCount}
                                                </label>                                    
                                        </div>
                                        <div className={toggle ? "dashboard__commentContent toggle" : "dashboard__commentContent"}>
                                                <div className="dashboard__postComments">
                                                    {post.comments.map((comment) => (
                                                        <div key={comment.toString()} className="dashboard__postComment">
                                                            <div className="dashboard__postCommentTop">
                                                                <Avatar src={comment.upic}/>
                                                                <h4>{comment.uname}</h4>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <p>{comment.message}</p>
                                                            <div className="dashboard__postCommentActions">
                                                            {comment.likes.find(like => like.uid === user._id) ? (
                                                                <FavoriteIcon onClick={() => UnlikeCommentPost(post._id, comment._id)} className="dashboard__actionUnlike"/>
                                                            ):(
                                                                <FavoriteBorderIcon onClick={() => LikeCommentPost(post._id, comment._id)} className="dashboard__actionLike"/>
                                                            )}              
                                                                <label id='totalLikes' className="dashboard__likes" style={{color: 'forestgreen'}}>
                                                                    {comment.likeCount}
                                                                </label>   
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    ))}        
                                                </div>

                                            <div className="dashboard__commentInput">
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Comment post" value={comment} onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}/>
                                                <button onClick={() => submitComment(post._id)}>Send</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </FlipMove>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dashboardContentRight">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
    getLike: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
    getPost: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
    likePost: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
    unlikePost: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        getPost: getPosts(state),
        getLike: getPostLikes(state),
        likePosts: likePost(state),
        unlikePosts: unlikePost(state),
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getAllPosts: (posts) => dispatch(getPosts(posts)),
        getAllLikes: (likes) => dispatch(getPostLikes(likes)),
        likePosts: (like) => dispatch(likePost(like)),
        unlikePosts: (like) => dispatch(unlikePost(like)),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Comment: You're creating a new listener for `posts` without ever removing them. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54830805/4384238

Comment: Do you happen to be rendering your app into a `React.StrictMode` component? It intentionally double invokes certain functions as a way to help you detect unintentional side-effects. Each time the effect hook callback runs you are adding another listener.

Comment: @DemiPixel - I've figured it should be something to do the use I'm making with the socket connections, so if I'm correct, since I'm making use of socket.on inside the useEffect, the connection really never ends up closing after the useEffect has occured right? thus forcing the rendering to take place twice? If I'm mistaken don't mind correcting me as I'm still new to the implementation of this.

Comment: `useEffect` is called on the first render--then again when `posts` is updated (after your API fetch). So now it's done `socket.on(` twice and you'll console.log twice every time there's a `post` event.

Comment: @DemiPixel - So I guess the link you have provided (which I am reading through now), would rather recommend on handling those connections regarding to the socket, to prevent it from logging twice in the console? If it's to much to ask, you don't mind providing a solution to what you've provided, just to check the similarities between the two, just to get two examples for understanding, if you can't I do respect and appreciate the help!

Comment: Generally, you need to declare socket io instance once only. Since your dependency array contains posts, it will re-create the listener every time posts change.  A good way is to isolate the socket into a onMount hook `[]` But it seems you are calling a REST endpoint to pre populate a initial data.  It might be good idea to create a state machine  e.g hasSeedData = true  which toggles to true when data has been fetched.  Then use that as a dependency in deps array so instantiate socket.io. Ofcourse, don't forget to do cleanups of socket to avoid multiple instance running at the same time.

Comment: @jameswilliams no worries, just make sure that you make use of the state machine on when to instantiate a socket instance, meaning, enclose the whole socket.io thing with a conditionals. If you are looking into a much more viable solution, you might want to look into socket.io on a webworker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `socket.on` and `socket.off` every single time a new post is sent would be unfortunate. Luckily, you can use `setPosts` without adding it to the dependencies list (I assume you want to `setPosts` and not just `console.log`):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (item) => {
    setPosts((oldPosts) => [...oldPosts, item]);
  };
  socket.on('posts', handler);
  // Otherwise you'll start getting errors when the component is unloaded
  return () => socket.off('posts', handler);
}, []);
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine!! one small issue I've been sitting which is kinda in the same boat, when I like the post, the state seems to reflect the old one first (unliked post) as well as the new state (liked post), how would I go about this? I have been looking at other suggestions but I've still been struggling to work around it, which doesn't make sense since setPosts((oldposts) => [...oldPosts, item]); has already made the array Iterable ? I guess somehow it needs to be updated before presenting duplicates, or the old state of that post should be removed before adding?

Comment: If the `posts` events returns all posts, just do `setPosts(item)`. If it returns both new and updated posts, you'll need to do something a bit fancier, such as `setPosts((oldPosts) => [...oldPosts.filter(p => p.id !== item.id), item])`, assuming posts that are identical have the same `id` property. The filter would remove the updated post from the existing posts array (if it's in there).